# How to get list of things in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

There's something about Retrofit that I'm not getting. I'm following examples on the web, but can't get it to even compile. I am able to access the data from the RESTful service via old school (i.e. HttpGet/HttpResoponse) so I know the service works. It returns a bunch of EmployeeData (as oppose to just one EmployeeData)

In the app gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    ...
}
```

The url for the RESTful service endpoint is:
https://com.somewhere/PhoneDirectoryService/api/Employees/

I have defined a string for the base url:

```
<string name="https_phone_directory_service_baseurl">https://com.somewherePhoneDirectoryService/api/</string>
```

Interface

```
public interface EmployeesService {
    @GET("Employees.json") //  the string in the GET is end part of the endpoint url
    public Call<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>> listEmployees();
}
```

Response

```
public class EmployeeEndpointResponse {

    private List<EmployeeData> employees; // EmployeeData is a POJO

    // public constructor is necessary for collections
    public EmployeeEndpointResponse() {
        employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeData>(); 
    }

    public static EmployeeEndpointResponse parseJSON(String response) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeData>>(){}.getType();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        EmployeeEndpointResponse employeeEndpointResponse = gson.fromJson(response, EmployeeEndpointResponse.class);
        return employeeEndpointResponse;
    }
}
```

Get the data

```
public static boolean getEmployeeData(Context context) {

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI(resources.getString(R.string.https_phone_directory_service_baseurl));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException exception) {
        Log.e("getEmployeeData", exception.toString());
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(uri.toString())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Call<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>> call = service.listEmployees();

    EmployeesService service = retrofit.create(EmployeesService.class);

    // this does not compile 
    // error: <anonymous com.somewhere.utilities.Utilities$1> is not 
    // abstract and does not override abstract method 
    // onFailure(Call<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>>,Throwable) in Callback
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>> response) {
            List<EmployeeEndpointResponse> myList = response.body();
            // Successfull request, do something with the retrieved messages
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // Failed request.
        }
    });

    // so I tried this which gives compile error
    // retrofit2.Callback<java.util.List   
    // <com.somewhere.gson.EmployeeEndpointResponse>>)
    // in Call cannot be applied to anonymous retrofit2.Callback  
    // <com.somewhere.gson.EmployeeEndpointResponse>)         
    call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeEndpointResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EmployeeEndpointResponse> call, Response<EmployeeEndpointResponse> response) {
            // handle response here
            EmployeeEndpointResponse employeeEndpointResponse = (EmployeeEndpointResponse)response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EmployeeEndpointResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });  

}
```

What do I need to do?

Data looks like:

```
[
{"Name":"Smith, Ken J.",
"Cell":"",
"EmailAddress":"Ken.Smith@somewhere.com",
"Location":"West",
"Phone":"555-555-5555",
"Address":"PO Box 555 5555 Del Norte",
"City":"Jackson",
"State":"WY",
"Zip":"85555",
"Latitude":42.24976,
"Longitude":-107.82171},

{"Name":"Cox, Daniel B.",
"Cell":"",
"EmailAddress":"daniel.cox@somewhere.com",
"Location":"West",
"Phone":"(555) 555-5516",
etc ...}
]
```

Comment: It seems you are not managing the http connections. It's recommendable to use OkHttp3 with Retrofit2

Comment: post an example of what the service returns.

Comment: `does not override abstract method onFailure(Call<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>>,Throwable) in Callback` what do you not understand about that?

Comment: It says to me that the signature is not correct, hence the 2nd attempt in which I added a `Call<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>>` parameter.

Comment: you do realize that is not json, right?

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I'm told by the author of the RESTful service that it can return xml or json.

Comment: What I show there is just the browser output from accessing the url. Nonetheless, I can't even get to that point, since my code doesn't compile.

Comment: I don't see a benefit to adding the URL as an Android String resource.  These are usually reserved for strings that the user will see.  I normally add these as static constant variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
}
```

Generate the http client

```
private static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();
    return okClient;
}
```

Getting the data

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(YOUR_URL)
        .client(getOkHttpClient())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
return retrofit;


EmployeesService service = retrofit.create(EmployeesService.class);
Call<EmployeeEndpointResponse> call = service.listEmployees();
call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeEndpointResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EmployeeEndpointResponse> call, Response<EmployeeEndpointResponse> response) {
            EmployeeEndpointResponse employeeEndpointResponse = response.body();
            //manage your response
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EmployeeEndpointResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Parsing JSON

Your POJO doesn't need any aditional methods to parse JSON. Just generate the code with GSON anotations with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: what's with the interceptor?

Comment: It's for logging the http connection. Setting HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

Comment: the second one sure, but the first one?

Comment: @JuliánMartínez: I'm working with your code, made a couple corrections to your answer (details, understandable) and I'm now getting the basically the same errors as in my question.

Comment: @JuliánMartínez: The error on the OnFailure method is `error: name clash: 
onFailure(Call<EmployeeEndpointResponse>,Throwable) in <anonymous utilities.Utilities$1> 
and onFailure(Call<T>,Throwable) 
in Callback have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in interface Callback`

Comment: I may have made a mistake in my edit to your answer. I replaced `ResourceTypeList` with `EmployeeEndpointResource` which perhaps is causing the error. But the code doesn't know what `ResourceTypeList` is.

Comment: You did right, that was my mistake by copy/pasting it from an example

Comment: Oh, it needs to be `Call<List<EmployeeEndpointResponse>> call`. That compiles. Now problems with getOkHttpClient() ... attempt to use incompatible return type - retrofit2.Response/okhttp3.Response.

Comment: @AlLelopath I removed the first interceptor which is not necessary.

Comment: Roger that .,. I've got it all compiling now.

Comment: @AlLelopath can you post an example of your JSON response?

Comment: Showing json data now.

Comment: Did you generate your pojo with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ ? Are you still having problems with getOkHttpClient?

Comment: I already have a POJO. I tried jsonschema2pojo anyway, it looks about the same as what I have.

Comment: Ok, just making sure you have in your pojo the gson annotations. Can you reach at least the onFailure method?

Comment: I'm in the onResponse() method. Got a successful response. Trying to get the data out.

Comment: I've added a line on the onResponse method in case you didn't have it. Hope the answer helped you.

Comment: Yeah, you're reading my mind :). Somethings not right, I think I need to change the EmployeeEndpointResponse because I'm not seeing individual employees.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124354/discussion-between-julian-martinez-and-al-lelopath).

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't see your last comment til this morning. I've got fires to put out this morning unrelated to this. I'll get back to this in a couple days.